# How do I edit a table in shiny before outputting it?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to write a shiny app to accommodate a specific function which estimates numbers of fish from sampled data. The function creates an amalgamated variable that is nonsense to the user. The code does run, but I am trying to modify this table after the fact to create variables that will make sense to the user. In order to do this, I need to split the nonsense variable into parts, rename those parts, and specify which ones to print. I can do this in the tidyverse using mutate, but haven't figured out how or where to incorporate these changes so that it doesn't kill the app.
I have tried a reactive within server. I have tried to perform these changes within renderTable.
In the code below, estimate is the output of the custom function MRIP.catch and the output needs to be modified. There is an output column called "domain" that conglomerates all of the inputs. I need to split these back apart so that the user knows what they are looking at in the table output.
I know this code isn't run-able on it's own. I was just hoping that it was a simple syntax question that someone could help me to untangle. I haven't been able to find examples of tables that need to be changed after being calculated but before being displayed.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

      sp<-eventReactive(input$go,{input$species})
      yr1<-eventReactive(input$go, {input$start_yr})
      yr2<-eventReactive(input$go, {input$end_yr})

freq2<-eventReactive(input$go,{
                               case_when(input$freq =='annual'~annual,
                                         input$freq =='wave'~wave) 
                                       
                                       })

sub<-eventReactive(input$go, {
                              case_when(input$reg =='by state'~state,
                                        input$reg =='by coast'~coast)
                                       })
mode<-eventReactive(input$go, {
                               case_when(input$modes=='all modes combined'~all_mode,
                                          input$modes=='all modes by mode'~each_mode) 
                                        })

area<-eventReactive(input$go, {
                               case_when(input$areas == 'all areas combined'~all_area,
                                         input$areas=='all areas by area'~each_area)
                                       })

dom1<- eventReactive(input$go, {list(wave=freq2()#Use for annual estimate. Comment out for wave
           ,sub_reg=sub() #Use for custom geo regions 
           ,mode_fx=mode() #use to combine modes. 
           ,area_x=area() #Use to combine fishing areas. 
           
)})


 estimate<-eventReactive(input$go,{
    MRIP.catch(intdir='C:\\Users\\', 
                      st = 12, styr = yr1(), endyr= yr2(), common = sp()
               , dom = dom1()
               )})
 

   
output$species <- renderText({paste( 'you have seletected',sp()) })
output$range<-renderText({paste ('from',yr1(), 'to', yr2())})
output$table<-renderTable({estimate()})
```

}

The following is the code I used in dplyr to create the independent sections of the variable and rename them. I'm sure it isn't the most elegant way to make this go, but it does work.

```
##Separates out each piece of domain to name 
estimate<-
estimate%>%
  mutate (yr = substr(Domain, 5,8),
      wave1=substr(Domain,13,13),
      basin1=substr(Domain,25,25),
      mode1=substr(Domain, 33,33),
      area1=substr(Domain, 40,40),
      cntys1=substr(Domain, 45,45),
      yr_wave=paste(yr,wave1, sep='-'))

estimate<-
    estimate%>%
      mutate (basin = case_when (basin1 == '6' ~'SA', 
                         basin1=='7'~'Gulf',
                         basin1=='1'~'statewide'
                         ),
           mode = case_when(mode1=='1'~'combined',
                            mode1 =='3'~'Shore',
                            mode1=='5'~'Charter',
                            mode1=='7'~'Private'),
           area = case_when(area1 =='1'~'EC state',
                            area1=='2'~'EC fed',
                            area1=='3'~'Gulf state',
                            area1=='4'~'Gulf fed',
                            area1=='5'~'Inland'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to focus on this part: "find examples of tables that need to be changed after being calculated but before being displayed".

Take a look at the example below and check if this is something which can help you.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df <- reactiveVal(data.frame(a = c(1, 2))) # but reactiveVal() can be left empty as well, then it starts with NULL value
  
  initial_data <- reactive({
    first_computation <- df() %>% 
      mutate(b = c(3, 4))
    df(first_computation )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    second_computation <- initial_data() %>% 
      mutate(c = c(5, 6))
    df(second_computation)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    req(input$go) # not sure if this will be enough for your needs!
    df()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I created `reactiveVal` object and this is most important part - this object can be use in different places (active-reactive context) and can be modify. At first is data.frame with one variable, then I made some computation, but do not display anything. Then I have made some new additional computation when user clicks "go" and after that the new table is displayed.